# Basic exercise differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, multilinear-algebra

I have to show that the space of *q-differential forms* $\Omega^q(U)=\{0\}$ if and only if $q>n$ or $q<0$.

Any ideas?

Comment: When $q>n$, then in local coordinates, you must have some $dx_i$ appearing twice in a wedge product and since a wedge product is alternating, the value is zero.

Comment: Yes, I understood this. But, what about the converse implication?

Comment: Locally, the wedge product won't vanish for distinct $dx_i$'s.